# Access actions from within an route in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm updating the following route:

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 events: {
   getMore: function(){
     var controller = this.get('controller'),
         nextPage   = controller.get('page') + 1,
         perPage    = controller.get('perPage'),
         items;

     items = this.events.fetchPage(nextPage, perPage);
     controller.gotMore(items, nextPage);
   },

   fetchPage: function(page, perPage){
     . . . .
   }
 }
});
```

For the most part, it works fine. However, the `events` syntax has been deprecated. Instead, we're suppose to use `actions`. Updating that works well enough, until I get to the line:

```
items = this.events.fetchPage(nextPage, perPage);
```

This throws the error:

```
TypeError: this.events is null
```

Unfortunately, I get the same error if I update the code to:

```
items = this.actions.fetchPage(nextPage, perPage);
=> TypeError: this.actions is null
```

How can I access action methods from within the same route?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use .send() to call a function inside the actions hash. Example:

```
    App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     actions: {
       getMore: function(){
         var controller = this.get('controller'),
             nextPage   = controller.get('page') + 1,
             perPage    = controller.get('perPage'),
             items;

        items = this.send('fetchPage', nextPage, perPage);
         controller.gotMore(items, nextPage);
      },

      fetchPage: function(page, perPage){
        .. . .
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: That does it. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, if you want to stub an action in one of your tests (e.g. with Sinon), then you can access the action with an underscore:

  sinon.spy(route._actions, 'getMore')

Don't do this in your regular code though.

Answer (score 6):

It's also worth noting that you could potentially move `fetchPage` out of the `actions` hash.  If it's only used 'internally' and does not respond directly to UI events, then it doesn't need to be in the `actions` hash.  Then you can just call it with :

```
items = this.fetchPage(nextPage, perPage);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `send(actionName, args...)` method to execute some action.

In your case:

```
this.send('fetchPage', nextPage, perPage);
```